# DOM Events API: event delegation and stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This is a code with jQuery 1.7:

```
<div class="test">
  <div class="bu">
    <a>
      bu here
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.test', function () { alert(0); return false; });
$(document).on('click', '.bu', function () { alert(1); return false; });
$(document).on('click', '.bu', function () { alert(2); return false; });
</script>
```

Xlicking on .test > .bu will alert "1" and alert "2", but not alerts "0"

My question is: how to do the same WITHOUT jQuery (on native DOM API)? Seems, I can't do it with Native DOM API without implementing my own library...

Comment: The title leads one to believe you have a question about stopPropagation. For what it's worth (not much, because you want NO jQuery!), in the jQuery supplied, you probably want to preventDefault rather than return false.

Comment: In Jquery they have handled internally the event delegation and stop propagation so that only it happens like that. Obviously in native DOM api you have to implement your own library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
      <div class="c" style="border: 1px solid silver; width: 80px; text-align: center;line-height: 80px;">
          click me!
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

// Element.prototype.matchesSelector
(function (x) {
  var i;
  if (!x.matchesSelector) {
    for (i in x) {
      if (/^\S+MatchesSelector$/.test(i)) {
        x.matchesSelector = x[i];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}(Element.prototype));

Document.prototype.on =
Element.prototype.on = function (eventType, selector, handler) {
  this.addEventListener(eventType, function listener(event) {
    var t = event.target,
      type = event.type,
      x = [];
    if (event.detail && event.detail.selector === selector && event.detail.handler === handler) {
      return this.removeEventListener(type, listener, true);
    }
    while (t) {
      if (t.matchesSelector && t.matchesSelector(selector)) {
        t.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
        x.push(t);
      }
      t = t.parentNode;
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
      var i = x.length - 1;
      while (i >= 0) {
        x[i].removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
        i -= 1;
      }
    }, 0);
  }, true);
};

Document.prototype.off =
Element.prototype.off = function (eventType, selector, handler) {
  var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
  event.initCustomEvent(eventType, false, false, {selector: selector, handler: handler});
  this.dispatchEvent(event);
};

document.on('click', '.b', function () {
  alert(2);
});
document.on('click', '.a', function () {
  alert(1);
});
document.on('click', '.b', function (event) {
  alert(3);
  event.stopPropagation();
});

</script>
```

Comment: idea from here: http://krijnhoetmer.nl/irc-logs/whatwg/20111117#l-420 , implemented by mysefl

Comment: Kudos to prototyping `Document` and `Element`. :)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Amazing. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 14):

Here you go:

```
document.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
    if ( hasClass( e.target, 'bu' ) ) {            
        // .bu clicked
        // do your thing
    } else if ( hasClass( e.target, 'test' ) ) {
        // .test clicked
        // do your other thing
    }   
}, false );
```

where `hasClass` is

```
function hasClass( elem, className ) {
    return elem.className.split( ' ' ).indexOf( className ) > -1;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Nrxp5/30/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a prototype based version

```
Document.prototype.on = function(event, target = null, callBack){
    this.addEventListener(event, function(event){
        let len = target.length, i = 0;
        while(i < len){
            if(event.target === target[i]){
                callBack.call(target[i], event);
            }
            i ++;
        }
    }, false);
};
```

Usage is like jQuery has:

```
let btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
document.on('click', btns, function(event){
    console.log(this.innerText)
});
```

And a live example is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000">
<button>hello1</button>
<button>hello2</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
 Document.prototype.on = function(event, target = null, callBack = function(){}){
  this.addEventListener(event, function(event){
   let len = target.length, i = 0;
   while(i < len){
    if(event.target === target[i]){
     callBack.call(target[i], event);
    }
    i ++;
   }
  }, false);
 };


//example of usage
 let btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
 document.on('click', btns, function(t){
  alert(this.innerText);
 })

//add elements after delegating an event
 let newBtn = document.createElement('button');
  newBtn.innerText = 'btnNew';
  document.body.appendChild(newBtn);
    
//delay to create
setTimeout(function(){
let newBtn = document.createElement('button');
  newBtn.innerText = 'another btnNew';
  document.body.appendChild(newBtn);
},2000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```